# Extended Event Failing To Capture Intent Locks

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, locking, extended-events

I have a SQL server with many unused databases and followed the linked article to set up an extended event to track intent locks and identify which DB's are actively being used, and which aren't and can be taken offline.

[Finding Inactive SQL Server Databases]https://www.red-gate.com/hub/product-learning/sql-monitor/finding-inactive-sql-server-databases

[image: Extended Event Settings]

By and large the results look great, however I have one database which refuses to report any intent locks over the few days that the event has been running, even though I know it is an actively used database.

All tables in this database are set to `TABLE` lock escalation.

I've even tried to force an intent lock myself by selecting and updating large amounts of data and blocking multiple transactions, but nothing registers.

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: Can you create a repro script? Definition of the XE and the tables + queries?

Comment: I'd probably take a step back and create a less restrictive XE session that captures all locks. Session filtering can be really tricky.